# Delay in void Start() function (C# Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

So what I want is my character to change position and jump depending on countdown, But how can I make this in start() function, I know about Update() function but there he will fly far away. Check the code, that's what I've tried, any ideas? Thanks.

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2de;
public float enemyJump;
float transformTime = 15.0f;


void Start()
{
    rb2de = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb2de.AddForce(new Vector2(rb2de.velocity.x, enemyJump));

    transformTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (Mathf.Round(transformTime) == 12) ;
    transform.position = new Vector3(4, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    rb2de.AddForce(new Vector2(rb2de.velocity.x, enemyJump / 12));



}
```

Comment: Are you expecting any input from the player during the game, or are you going to be moving the character based on timing only? Is your countdown going to restart or reset or change duration? I see some issues with only using the `Start` method and not `Update` like most solutions would use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all u need is to use Coroutine. for example

```
void Start()
{
   rb2de = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
   rb2de.AddForce(new Vector2(rb2de.velocity.x, enemyJump));
   StartCoroutine($yourname());
}
IEnumerator $yourname()
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds($waitingTime)
   transform.position = new Vector3(4, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
   rb2de.AddForce(new Vector2(rb2de.velocity.x, enemyJump / 12));
}
```

Comment: You can make `Start` a coroutine itself.

Comment: didnt know. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Function Start can be a coroutine ,try this

IEnumerator Start()
{
 ...
yield return new WaitForSeconds( 12f );
 ...
}